# Bluetooth failed to find any device

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth is installed correctly but when clicking on "SET UP NEW DEVICE" option its searching seems never end. and it is showing nothing for pairing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.